# Как преобразовать сайты из списка в pdf?

Tags: c#, pdf

Как,имея распарсеный список страниц ссылок сайта скачать все его ссылки и затем преобразовать в один большой pdf на c# либо другом языке? Желательно не качая всю страницу,а только начиная с определённого элемента/класса,выкинув рекламу и ненужные элементы.
Пока я нашёл wkhtmltopdf.org но здесь указано по одному pdf на одну страницу,а мне нужно сразу много страниц в один(конечно их можно и склеить потом другой библиотекой), но ещё и нужно отделить ненужные элементы и создать pdf только на основании их,а не всех данных сайта

Comment: По идее, ваш вопрос нужно разделить на два или даже три: 1. как пройтись по дереву/ссылкам сайтам, избегая зацикливания и не уходя на другие сайты; 2. как распарсить содержимое, убрав ненужное; 3. как преобразовать в pdf.

Comment: По первому пункту советую поискать готовые утилиты для скачивания сайтов offline. Зачем изобретать велосипед, если есть готовое? Раньше, лет десять назад, они пользовались популярностью. По второму пункту: если сайт предоставляет API для получения данных - воспользуйтесь им. В противном случае используйте любой html-парсер.

Answer (score 0):

могу только посоветовать такое:
в c# есть такая функция DownloadString в WebClient, она скачивает html код страницы, потом вручную удалить блоки рекламы
есть там же функция DownloadFile, которая скачивает содержимое
вот например

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) 
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/page.html", @"C:\localfile.html");

    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/page.html");
}
```

ну а потом юзать библиотеку, которая сделает pdf, но это уже отдельная головная боль